# Hosting a static ruby site on heroku, and adding pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have just finished following this tutorial on Heroku's website:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby

Everything works fine and I can access my index.html file and all images, css and js when I run my local server.

The question I have is: How do I add another page? Right now, only the index.html page works as the root, but I have one other page called /faq.html (also in my public folder).

When I try and access it through the navbar on the website (on my running local server), it just reloads the root url again. How can I root to this page?

Thanks for the help

Comment: does going to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/faq.html` work when you go there manually? (or `your_url/faq.html`)

Comment: I managed to figure it out. In config.ru I had to add "/faq" to the :url list:

:urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css", "/faq"],